# Contacts notes entitlement not showing in app store provisioning profile in xcode

Tags: ios, contacts, code-signing-certificate, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

We have applied for com.apple.developer.contacts.notes entitlement to apple and got the option enabled in app id. We created an app store provisioning profile with this app id and we can see that this entitlement is enabled in developer site.

[image]

But when downloading and using the same provisioning profile in xcode, it is showing error "Provisioning profile "MyApp_AppStore" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.contacts.notes entitlement."

[image]

Why is this happening? I have added com.apple.developer.contacts.notes YES in entitlements file. Please help us figure out why this error is coming?

Comment: did you the check it after click on info icon next to provisioning profile, also try to update provisioning from Xcode.

Comment: Info icon is showing 1 missing entitlement. Deleting all provisioning profiles and downloading through xcode also didn't help.

Comment: @RounakKiran Whats the update bro? Also do we have to create entitlements file manually ?